# How can the same post be closed as 'opinion-based' and marked as community wiki?

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic, closing-questions, community-wiki

I have to admit that I don't know much about the Community Wiki concept. I thought it would denote questions that were either particularly interesting, or which by their own nature would attract a lot of useful answers/references, as opposed to a single "right" answer. User whuber has made my recent post

[MOOCs for Python in Data Science](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/288423/moocs-for-python-in-data-science)

a Community Wiki post and put it on hold. I'm a little confused here - how can the same post be eligible for closure and at the same time be "worth" of the Community Wiki tag? Of course I asked directly whuber, but I wonder if my confusion underlines a fundamental misunderstanding on my part of the Community Wiki attribute.

Comment: The answer has evolved.  I linked your question to its duplicates, but please note the dates associated with each.  I don't see any logical conflict between the concepts of "CW" and "not quite on topic here."  I routinely set any question that potentially would get a list of different answers as CW, regardless of whether it is currently on topic.

Comment: @whuber so a post on MOOCs about Nouvelle Cousine would be CW here, because it potentially has a lot of answers...I don't see the logic of marking a post which you think is off-topic, as CW.

Comment: Sure, a post about MOOCs on cooking would be CW--but nobody would even bother to make it CW, because it would be deleted or migrated first.  The only reason I bothered to make your question CW was anticipating you would modify it and the community would vote to re-open it.  At that point it would *still* require moderator intervention to make it CW, so why wait?

Comment: @whuber because closing a question can be undone, while marking a question as CW cannot, so maybe you could have waited  a to see the new question. I think marking a question as CW before it even gets an answer makes it much less likely to get any answer at all. Anyway, questions about book/paper references are not routinely marked as CW, even though by their own nature they can admit more than one answer. Your point is that making it about MOOCs makes it CW, because MOOCs are temporary. I'd like to hear also somebody's else opinion on this.

Comment: On the contrary, questions asking for lists of references *are* routinely marked CW.  If you have a different impression, that is only because some of these do not come to moderators' attention--and that's precisely why I always make such a question CW automatically, as soon as I come across it.  Your other objections appear to be rehashing the discussion in the duplicate questions.

Comment: About your last comment, see: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1593/should-all-book-recommendation-questions-be-classified-as-community-wiki (/cc @whuber).

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but technically speaking the question was closed as 'opinion-based', not 'off-topic'. These two close reasons have the same hierarchy in the close reason dialog box, which means in this context a question needs to be both 'on-topic' and not 'opinion-based'.

Comment: @whuber ok. None of my older reference requests was marked as CW, and I also recall a few other requests not being tagged as CW. Spince you pointed out the MOOC component of the question, I thought that was the cause of the CW tag. I see now that's not the case. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @AndreSilva comment #1: ok, I see now all reference requests *should* be tagged as CW. But in practice that happens (or used to happen until recently) so rarely, that I can't be blamed for feeling my question had been singled out because of the MOOC part. I see this is not the case.

Comment: @AndreSilva comment #2: ok, but my point was that either a question is opinion-based ("worse" than CW, but can be undone) or it is CW (can't be undone, question stays open, but usually **if** it's tagged as CW **before** it has received an answer, then it's unlikely to get any answer at all). I don't think you should tag the same question as both, otherwise that means the two definition are unclear and overlapping.

Comment: Ps sorry for the attitude. I'm having a rough time (unrelated to work) and while I try not to have that show up in my Internet persona, sometimes I may not be successful.

Comment: It depends on the nature of the reference request. A request for a *specific* reference shouldn't be CW ('can someone point me to the paper that proved...'), but open-ended reference requests should be CW ('what is a good book to learn...'). If you know of non-CW instances of the latter, we have just missed them. Flag them & the mods will make them CW.