# 3 upvotes (on answer) yielded only 10 reputation. Why not 30?

Tags: support, answers, reputation, community-wiki

Yesterday, I posted this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/350970/117812
which yielded 3 upvotes, no downvote.

My "latest achievements" (goblet icon) says that I have achieved 10 reputation yesterday, i. e. 10 reputation on this answer. I think, it should have been 30.
The difference of 20 reputation is not important to me, nor do I think this particular answer was worth more then 10 reputation, but reporting a possible bug in the forum software might be important.

Is this a bug and if so, do I need to report it anywhere else then here?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's "community wiki". See [meta-tag:community-wiki]. The reason you got 10 rep at all, is that the thread was converted to CW status after you already got 10 rep, and the rep points are not retroactively removed in this situation.

Comment: Ok, it's good to know, there is no bug but a special situation called "community wiki" od "CW". I read the link and do not quite get to the point of it, but that is fine. Thank you.

Comment: Here is official SE information: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts. Here on CV, we use CW status in a particular way and looking at the most upvoted Meta threads with this tag should give you some idea about how it's used: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-wiki?sort=votes. Specifically about reference requests, see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1593.

Comment: @amoeba Thank you for the great links. I take away, that I did not overlook something obvious, but that it is a complicated matter. Reference requests bare special risks and as a general rule "All this type of questions need to be community wiki to prevent the reputation-only-motivation to answer this type of questions" (from one of the links). That is a great answer.